# SQL Server hourly transaction log network share

Tags: sql-server, networking, share

The business and I decided to have RPO (Recovery Point Objective) of maximum 1 hour with our SQL server 2008. I would like to create an hourly transaction backup to a networkshare to secure the latest transactions. Would the hourly backup cause a temporarily database wait/blockage when writing to a networkshare, especially when there were lots of mutation during this past hour?

```
BACKUP LOG [DBNAME] 
TO DISK = N'<PATH>' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'<NAME>', 
     SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  
     STATS = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't incur blocking from within SQL Server (that is, you won't see a process being blocked explicitly by your backup), but you will be contending for server resources (namely disk and network since you're backing up to a remote target). Do it on a test system and make sure you're okay.

As an aside, if it were me, I'd do more frequent log backups (say every 15 minutes); a business-defined RPO should *inform* your backup strategy, but not *define* it.